# In Frege how can I convert an String safely to a Maybe Int?

Tags: java, haskell, converters, option-type, frege

In [Frege](https://github.com/Frege/frege/?tab=readme-ov-file#what-is-frege) I want to convert an String to an Int, but need to handle unparsable strings too.

So I guess I'm looking for something like a `readMaybe` function. Where do I find this? Or how can I use Java's `parseInt` and catch the exception in Frege?

Comment: [seems](https://github.com/y-taka-23/learn-you-a-frege/blob/master/src/main/frege/learnyou/chapter13/SomeUsefulMonadicFunctions.fr#L33C19-L33C19) like you can just do `myStr.double`, which returns an `Either`?

Comment: @mb21 Works perfectly - and is easily adapted for my case of `Int`s! How did you find this?

Comment: Great, I added it as an aswer. Found it by googling for `frege readMaybe` and clicked on the first GitHub link :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Frege, it's as simple as:

```
myStr.double
```

which returns an `Either`.

(Found this in the [Frege Translation of "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!."](https://github.com/y-taka-23/learn-you-a-frege/blob/master/src/main/frege/learnyou/chapter13/SomeUsefulMonadicFunctions.fr#L33))